# How to modify default shortcuts target from home screen bar ?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, galaxy, rom, homescreen

I'm removing the bloatware from my providers ROM. I've achieved this without problems. My problem is that when I try to open up the MMS shortcut from the home screen bar it says "App isn't installed". Whats interesting is that if I open the MMS app from the applications menu it opens up without a problem.

That behavior makes me believe that the application shortcut that's being generated in the installation process has a wrong target.

Where can I modify the "target" of this shortcut? Do I have to decompile the MMS apk in order to fix this?

Please remember I'm not creating an application. I'm modifying an existing rom.

Comment: What ROM/Launcher are you using?

Comment: Launcher:Trebuchet
Rom:I9100UHLPP_I9100UWALP5_PCT